# How exactly docker prevents time changes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I am aware that directly setting the time from inside a container is not permitted by default, i.e. when I run:

```
date -s 10:10
```

I get an error stating: `date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted`

I ran the container with

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu:latest
```

So the process itself has root privileges.
From inside the container I run:

- `whoami` -> results in `root`
- `ls -l /bin/date` -> results in `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`

So Actually I have sufficient permissions and should be able to run it.

I undertstand that there is another mechanism preventing me from setting the data, and my question is how exactly is that achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Docker uses [seccomp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/), which is a syscall filter – it can whitelist or blacklist specific kernel calls, e.g. block module loading or time adjustment.

Docker can use [AppArmor](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/), which is a security module designed to enforce per-app policies beyond ordinary UID-based privileges. (Some distributions use AppArmor even for standard apps.)

Docker can also use [user namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/), which allow each container to have distinct UIDs from the host system. Your container processes *think* they are uid 0, but only have root-like privileges within their own domain (user namespace), while the host system sees a normal non-root uid. Each container's uid 0 is also separate from every other container's uid 0.